# Loading CSV file into bigquery after os.Create() doesn't load data

Tags: go, google-bigquery

I'm trying to run the following flow:

1. Get data from somewhere
2. Create new local CSV file, write the data into that file
3. Upload the CSV to Bigquery
4. Delete the local file

But it seems to load empty data.
This is the code:

```
func (c *Client) Do(ctx context.Context) error {
    bqClient, err := bigquerypkg.NewBigQueryUtil(ctx, "projectID", "datasetID")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    data, err := c.GetSomeData(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    file, err := os.Create("example.csv")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer file.Close()
    // also file need to be delete

    writer := csv.NewWriter(file)
    defer writer.Flush()

    timestamp := time.Now().UTC().Format("2006-01-02 03:04:05.000000000")
    for _, d := range data {
        csvRow := []string{
            d.ID,
            d.Name,
            timestamp,
        }
        err = writer.Write(csvRow)
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("error writing data to CSV: %v\n", err)
        }
    }

    source := bigquery.NewReaderSource(file)
    source.Schema = bigquery.Schema{
        {Name: "id", Type: bigquery.StringFieldType},
        {Name: "name", Type: bigquery.StringFieldType},
        {Name: "createdAt", Type: bigquery.TimestampFieldType},
    }
    if _, err = bqClient.LoadCsv(ctx, "tableID", source); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

`LoadCSV()` looks like this:

```
func (c *Client) LoadCsv(ctx context.Context, tableID string, src bigquery.LoadSource) (string, error) {
    loader := c.bigQueryClient.Dataset(c.datasetID).Table(tableID).LoaderFrom(src)
    loader.WriteDisposition = bigquery.WriteTruncate
    job, err := loader.Run(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    status, err := job.Wait(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return job.ID(), err
    }

    if status.Err() != nil {
        return job.ID(), fmt.Errorf("job completed with error: %v", status.Err())
    }

    return job.ID(), nil
}
```

After running this, bigquery does create the schema but with no data.
If I'm changing `os.Create()` to `os.Open()` and the file already exist, everything work. It's like when loading the CSV the file data is not yet written (?)
What's the reason?

Comment: You do not check errors from Flush and Close, but you must—especially the first one: it might well be possible that the data did not land in the file.

Comment: Another point: it seems like the flushing and closing are deferred but you attempt to read file before the end of _the same_ function it's being written in, so those deferred calls are only executed after the function quits. It may well explain the observed problem: all the data to be written is still buffered at the time the file is read. Move all the CSV file creation code into a separate function and call it before passing the file to "bigquery" (whatever that means).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I see here is that you don't rewind the file handle's cursor to the beginning of the file.  Thus, the next read will be at the *end* of the file, and will be a 0 byte read.  That explains why it seems like there's no content in the file.

https://pkg.go.dev/os#File.Seek can handle this for you.

Actually, the `Flush` is not relevant, because you're using the same file handle to *read* the file than you did to *write* it, so you'll see your own written bytes even *without* a flush.  This would not be the case if the file was opened by a different process or was reopened.

Edit: OP Claims this flush was necessary in their case and I cannot provide evidence to disagree.  Flush will not *hurt* things either.

Demonstration:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    f, err := os.CreateTemp("", "data.csv")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    } else {
        defer f.Close()
        defer os.Remove(f.Name())
    }
    fmt.Fprintf(f, "hello, world")
    fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "Before rewind: ")
    if _, err := io.Copy(os.Stderr, f); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    f.Seek(0, io.SeekStart)
    fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "\nAfter rewind: ")
    if _, err := io.Copy(os.Stderr, f); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "\n")
}
```

```
% go run t.go
Before rewind:

After rewind:
hello, world
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked as expected after setting the cursor to the begining of the file. Actually the `Flush()` is relevant, and it need to be called before loading to Bigquery, otherwise the data is not fully written